# CSS Select 3rd adjacent element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Considering the html structure below, I am trying to select *only the third child* of the parent `div` based on the *unique href attribute* of the first child e.g. `a[href*="/view/12345"]`.

Limitations:

1. I cannot add ids or other classes to the html
2. The parent `div` is repeated on other pages but the first child anchor href attribute will be unique for each different page

```
    <div class="w-full rounded-lg shadow-md overflow-hidden bg-white text-gray-800 pb-4">
        <a href="/products/units/view/12345">...</a> 
        <div class="p-4 pb-0">
             <h2 class="text-lg font-semibold">...</h2>
             <div class="mt-4 my_content border-b">
                 ...
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex w-full p-4">
             <div class="flex-none my-auto my_custom_text">
                 STYLE ME GREEN
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried:

```
a[href*="/view/12345"] < div { 
   color: #46845f;}
```

Comment: `a[href*="/view/1038153"] + * + div` ?

Comment: You're going to have to explain how that works, but your solution selected the `<div class="flex w-full p-4">` element and I added `.my_custom_text` to the end and it selects the correct element! Genius! You want to add that as a solution, I'll accept it for you.

Comment: @ZephyrMays [**The adjacent sibling selector (+)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) it selects the next immediate sibling element and chaining it will keep selecting the next sibling of the previously selected element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to consider the parent element, simply use [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) like below

```
a[href*="/view/12345"] + * + div
```

This will simply select the *next* `div` after the *next* element after your link with its `href`. This will be your third child considering the fact that your link will always be the first.

```css
a[href*="/view/12345"] + * + div {
  color:green
}
```

```html
<div class="w-full rounded-lg shadow-md overflow-hidden bg-white text-gray-800 pb-4">
  <a href="/products/units/view/12345">...</a>
  <div class="p-4 pb-0">
    <h2 class="text-lg font-semibold">...</h2>
    <div class="mt-4 my_content border-b">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex w-full p-4">
    <div class="flex-none my-auto my_custom_text">
      STYLE ME GREEN
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="w-full rounded-lg shadow-md overflow-hidden bg-white text-gray-800 pb-4">
  <a href="/products/units/view/12945">...</a>
  <div class="p-4 pb-0">
    <h2 class="text-lg font-semibold">...</h2>
    <div class="mt-4 my_content border-b">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex w-full p-4">
    <div class="flex-none my-auto my_custom_text">
      DON'T STYLE ME
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```